# "Catch" StackOverFlowException when running Tests via Debug in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, integration-testing, stack-overflow

Stack Overflow exceptions can be a PITA to find.

Given situation where the StackOverflowException is reproduced in a (non-trivial) Integration Test running within a single process, the standard behavior is that the "test runner will crash" without useful information.

**Is there a way to detect which method(s) resulted in the SOE?**

- The SOE doesn't need to be 'actually caught' (*please don't link to questions about SOE being uncatchable in C# unless they provide insight on gathering useful stack information*); this is for finding the SOE/stack in a controlled Test environment with an available Debugger attached.
- The tests are run "with Debugger", if there is some magic there (eg. a dynamic breakpoint on stack depth?) that can be utilized it may fulfill this ask.
- Environment/tools: VS 2015 Professional, R# 2016.3 Task Runner, NUnit framework.

Comment: And where would you put that conditional breakpoint from the link above? I mean you have to put it in a method that is part of infinite recursion, but then your problem is already solved.

Comment: @Evk I just realized that. I got too excited :( - http://www.forbeslindesay.co.uk/post/47974551480/a-tip-for-debugging-stack-overflow-exceptions-in contains information on adding a Condition to a breakpoint, but how to add a "universal conditional breakpoint"?

Comment: But if you run with debugger attached, doesn't it break when this exception is thrown at the exact location? For me it does (with nunit and resharper test runner).

Comment: @Evk Arg, I do!! :} It appears that on my early test runs the source/library build was out of date so it just said "nope".. the debugger is now taking me to the 'correct stack' at the SOE.

Comment: @Evk Well, I take that back. It *sometimes* does.. it might be related to crossing to external code boundaries?

Comment: If it breaks but you are not sure where - open "call stack" window in VS and look at callstack.

Comment: I have `[external code] OneStackTraceOfMine [external code]` listed at the time of the exception for the actual issue site. When it was JUST my code (simulated SOE fudge) I was able to see the entire stack :}

Comment: I disabled Just My Code and it looks like the stack is lost at "Native To Managed Transition". I now know *what* is causing the exception now, which is very good and allows me to proceed - still a bit miffed it's not a nice cyclic stack being displayed :}

Comment: So then you now know that issue is related to methods from OneStackTraceOfMine, but actual overflow happens in some native code (doesn't necessary means that native code is guilty).

Comment: @Evk Well no.. I don't know. *sigh*. Now I get a SOE without any stack listed in the Call Stack, so I think the previous stack was "misleading".

Comment: @Evk Well, it's just an epic fail on my part. Once again, a *secondary* module wasn't rebuilt so this was the same as the first issue of 'no stack' - the VS Debugger goes into a "limp mode" on an SOE. It does appear that threading may also 'throw off' the reported stack. This project is not setup correctly to rebuild the dependencies if they have changes :-/ In any case I was able to track down the SOE's location in the end.

Comment: Well that's what important after all. Hopefully my comments helped to track down that exception :)

Comment: @Evk They did :) Thanks for your time. If you'd toss in another close vote for "non-reproducible", it would be appreciated..